# Magento 2. I want to remove magento copyright links in Admin Panel

Tags: magento, admin

I would like to remove the `magento` copyright link from the admin panel from `Magento 2.1.6` community edition. I am unable to find the appropriate file to do so

Its a hosted solution but I have access to `FTP` / `FileManager`

Comment: What have you tried, have you searched for any solutions and tried them? Why are you not able to find the appropriate file. Please provide more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Open admin panel and go to content > design > Configuration > Edit your selected theme > Footer > Copyright.

Hope this will work.